# Ashley Outdated / Cannot Be Updated (Family.all() does not exist)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

I'm trying to get Ashley up and running, but I've run into an issue.  I try to call Family.all(), but IntelliJ IDEA 14 assures me that this function cannot be accessed.  Here's the system I'm trying to run it in:

```
package com.mygdx.game.Systems;

import com.badlogic.ashley.core.*;
import com.badlogic.ashley.utils.ImmutableArray;
import com.mygdx.game.Components.PositionComponent;
import com.mygdx.game.Components.VelocityComponent;

import javax.management.ImmutableDescriptor;

public class MovementSystem extends EntitySystem {
    private ImmutableArray<Entity> entities;

    private ComponentMapper<PositionComponent> pm = ComponentMapper.getFor(PositionComponent.class);
    private ComponentMapper<VelocityComponent> vm = ComponentMapper.getFor(VelocityComponent.class);

    public MovementSystem() {}

    public void addedToEngine(Engine engine) {
        entities = engine.getEntitiesFor(Family.all(PositionComponent.class, VelocityComponent.class).get());
    }

    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        for (int i = 0; i < entities.size(); ++i) {
            Entity entity = entities.get(i);
            PositionComponent position = pm.get(entity);
            VelocityComponent velocity = vm.get(entity);

            position.x += velocity.x * deltaTime;
            position.y += velocity.y * deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'SomeApp'
        gdxVersion = '1.4.1'
        roboVMVersion = '1.0.0-alpha-04'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.3'
        ashleyVersion = '1.3.2'
        aiVersion = '1.4.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-desktop:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

The error I get specifically is "all has private access".  The only thing auto-complete tells me I can access is "getFor()", from the Family class.  The Engine, Entities, and so on all work without a hitch so far.  I'm running JDK 7 both as the JDK that's installed on my machine, and as the compatibility mode in Intellij.

I took all of the code from the git readme, and followed the instructions for insuring Ashley is built in as a dependency, although I also included it when I first created the project.

I tried different versions of Ashley (I think), and I tried changing the JDK compatibility in Intellij and so far nothing.  I'm completely stumped here, and I appreciate any help.

Edit:  Recently the "all" function was added to the Family class, so the best I can surmise is that despite pushing Ashlety 1.3.2 as a dependency, it's still using an old version of Ashley before the builder pattern was added to the Family class.  The issue seems to be that Gradle is not using the most up-to-date version of Ashley.  That gets me closer, but I still can't figure out how to fix it.  I've followed the instructions for installation as well as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured it out while working on something unrelated.  I noticed an XML file referenced Ashley 1.0.1, which was WAY prior to the all() function being added to the Family class.  I don't know if this XML file causing the problem, but this reminded me that at some point I had seen, in File>Project Structure a "Dependencies" tab.

So I went there, and clicked on "core", and when I looked I noticed that despite what my build.gradle was telling me, the project was still referencing Ashley 1.0.1 or some other older version.  So I removed that outdated version of Ashley, hit the Add button (alt+insert), clicked Library, then clicked New Library, then clicked From Maven.

From there, you get a dialogue with a search bar, just type in "ashley" and it'll give you a list of the versions of Ashley you've used the gradle script to download.  Version 1.3.2 is the one you're looking for (1.3.3 gave me an error that I have no desire to workaround considering the documentation recommends 1.3.2 anyway).  If it doesn't show up after you hit OK on the search, make sure you add that version number to the build.gradle and run the dependencies build.

After that, you just hit okay, apply, etc. and get out.  From there, Family.all() works! and Ashley is updated the newest version.  Hopefully this answer helps someone else, even though it only applies to Intellij (and Eclipse seems to be more popular), because I about ripped my hair out trying to figure it out and there's not a lot of information out there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all as per the [ashley's java api doc](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ashley/docs/index.html?com/badlogic/ashley/core/Family.html)
Family.all(PositionComponent.class, VelocityComponent.class).get() **Families can't be instantiated directly but must be accessed via a builder** ( start with Family.all(), Family.one() or Family.exclude() ), this is to avoid duplicate families that describe the same components.

[Ashleys Family Class Source Code from the GitHub for your reference](https://github.com/libgdx/ashley/blob/master/ashley/src/com/badlogic/ashley/core/Family.java)

Comment: I'd downvote this answer if I could, but I don't have enough rep yet.  If you look at my question, you can see that I'm not trying to directly instantiate the Family class, I'm using the builder.  Basically, the problem is that even though I've added Ashely 1.3.2 as a dependency, it's still using an old version of Ashley where the "all" function doesn't exist on the Family class yet.  It's likely a problem with Gradle, not my code.

Comment: I am sorry, I thought maybe this will help you out. I should have read your question carefully .Please downvote my answer when you get the required reputation. Glad you resolved this.

Comment: No, I'm the one who's sorry.  In more ways than one.  For what it's worth, I'm embarrassed that I reacted that way.  It wasn't even about the question, I was just frustrated about something else and overreacted.  I know you were trying to help, and I was a jerk about it.  Sorry I did that.